# How to place exceptions in files?

Tags: c#

I have different kinds of exceptions in a library which i am developing.

What do you recommend placing them in a single file or a file with each kind of exception?

Pls answer remembering that this is a library i am developing.

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't do polls.  Also, this will be different in C# and Java.

Comment: In Java, 1 exception per file, because you have to.

Comment: i removed the java tag..and polls

Comment: In C#, group related exceptions in the same file.

Comment: Why are you thinking of putting in a single file? You may need to open one file locate the exception class and do modification if required in future. If we have separate files its easy just locate the file modify checkin. If you are maintaining single file its ok but if multiple users are going to maintain then they may change at other places also by mistake as file is a big one and if some one changes in unrequired place then its a problem .

Comment: because i have seen putting them in a single file in C5 Collection library..

Comment: Well i have given answer w.r.to java. Now i see you have removed java tag :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, all public classes, including exceptions, *must* get their own file.

In C#, it is OK to put exceptions along with other classes, particularly if the exception is only raised by the other class.